# How to choose between different options in partial least square regression?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, least-squares, partial-least-squares

There seem to be several methods of performing partial least square regression. For example in pls pacakge in R, following are available:

```
partial least squares regression (PLSR)
canonical powered partial least squares (CPPLS) 
principal component regression (PCR)
```

There is also a generic mvr() function which I am not clear performs which kind of regression.

Validation can be used, either cross-validation 'CV' or leave-one-out cross-validation 'LOO' or not at all ('none')

Methods may be kernelpls, simpls, widekernelpls, classical orthogonal scores algorithm

How should one choose amongst these options? Is the generic form with all default options given below valid for most situations?

```
mod = mvr(y ~ x, data=mydata)
```

The question is also important since different methods give different results. I performed regression using these functions with modified birthwt package of MASS. The variables low and bwt are kept as outcome variables while others are kept as predictor variables.

```
> str(bwdf)
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ low  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
 $ age  : int  19 33 20 21 18 21 22 17 29 26 ...
 $ lwt  : int  182 155 105 108 107 124 118 103 123 113 ...
 $ race : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ smoke: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ ptl  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ht   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ui   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ftv  : int  0 3 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ bwt  : int  2523 2551 2557 2594 2600 2622 2637 2637 2663 2665 ...
> library(pls)
> mod1 = pslr(cbind(scale(low), scale(bwt))~., data=bwdf, scale=T)
> mod2 = pcr(cbind(scale(low), scale(bwt))~., data=bwdf, scale=T)
> mod3 = cppls(cbind(scale(low), scale(bwt))~., data=bwdf, scale=T)
> biplot(mod1, which = "loadings")
> biplot(mod2, which = "loadings")
> biplot(mod3, which = "loadings")
```

[image]

The three graphs show different relation between outcome and predictor variables. Which method of partial least square regression (plsr, pcr or cppls) should I use for this data? Or should I use traditional linear regression and logistic regression separately for bwt and low variables? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: +1, but note that "principal component regression" is not an instance of PLS regression, it's a different method.

Comment: The 3 methods give different results: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157605/which-method-of-partial-least-square-regression-for-this-data  so it is important to know which one to use when.

Comment: Hmm, should these two questions perhaps be merged into one? It's not clear to me why you are asking it twice.

Comment: I have merged both questions into this one and deleted the other post.